# How to set tabindex for elements on webpage with similar class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, tabindex

I have multiple elements with anchor tag as below, I am trying to set tabindex only to elements with the anchor tag. Below is the code:

```
<ul class="level1 static" tabindex="0" role="menu" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;">

        <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;">
        <a class="level1 static" >program details<span class="visuallyhidden">(Current page)</span></a>
</ul>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, with `$("a").attr('tabindex', 0);` you will add/set `tabindex="0"` to all `a` element.

(NOTE: make sure the above code run after all your `<a>` element are loaded, for dynamic added `<a>` element just call it again after the new `<a>` element loaded.)

> ## tabindex
>
> The tabindex attribute is versatile, and it has the capacity to improve or destroy usability for keyboard-only users. When you think about using the tabindex attribute, keep these things in mind:
>
> **Use tabindex=0** to include an element in the natural tab order of the content, but remember that an element that is focusable by default may be an easier option than a custom control
>
> **Use tabindex=-1** to give an element programmatic focus, but exclude it from the tab order of the content
>
> **Avoid using tabindex=1+.**
>
> REF: https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/08/using-the-tabindex-attribute/
>
> ```js
> //$("a").attr('tabindex', 0);
>
>
> $("li.static").each(function(index, elm) {
>   $($(elm).find('a')).attr('tabindex', 0);
> });
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <ul class="level1 static" tabindex="0" role="menu" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;">
>
>   <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;">
>     <a class="level1 static">program details<span class="visuallyhidden">(Current page)1</span></a><br>
>   </li>
>   <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;">
>     <a class="level1 static">program details<span class="visuallyhidden">(Current page)2</span></a><br>
>   </li>
>   <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;">
>     <a class="level1 static">program details<span class="visuallyhidden">(Current page)3</span></a><br>
>   </li>
>
> </ul>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want tabindex to increase with each anchor tag. Example, first tagindex = 0 for first anchor, tabindex = 1 for second anchor and so on..

Comment: @Chaitanya ok simple wait 1 sec

Comment: @Chaitanya ok code updated, but why you want increasing tabindex, it is not going to work since you will just loop through all tabindex 0 element (include those in browswer).

Comment: I used this code and it perfectly adds tab index to all required anchor tags but when I press tab button, none of them are being selected. 

`$("li.static").each(function(index, elm){
                $($(elm).find('a')).attr('tabindex', index+1);
            });`

Comment: @Chaitanya you need them to be all 0 to tab though.

Comment: @Chaitanya check the updated code, use $("li.static").each(function(index, elm) {
  $($(elm).find('a')).attr('tabindex', 0);
});

Comment: @Chaitanya take a look at: http://adrianroselli.com/2014/11/dont-use-tabindex-greater-than-0.html

Comment: Thank you :) Problem Solved!!

Comment: @Chaitanya Cool =D I also updated a simple use case for `tabindex`. Good luck coding!

Answer (score 1):

Can use `attr(attributeName, function)`

```
$("a").attr('tabindex',function(i) {
  return  i + 1;
});
```